# Why isActive() function in java work in windows and doesn't work in ubuntu

Tags: java, windows, ubuntu

Why `isActive()` function run correctly in windows and doesn't run in ubuntu?
I used this function in the code below to make the program wait until the `myFrame` JFrame Window being closed and this worked in windows only.

```
MyFrame myFrame = new MyFrame();  // This class Extends jFrame to show a Jframe
myFrame.run();
while (myFrame.isActive()) {
    sleep(500);  // this another function in this class to delay the program for 500 mS
}
```

Why this happen and how to deal with this !?

Comment: I would imagine there is no guarantee that the frame will instantaneously be active as soon as you request that it be made visible, and not a few moments later. Busy-waiting for it to become inactive is a bad pattern. Why don't you add a window listener or window focus listener to it and perform an action when it is deactivated, closed, or loses focus?

Comment: @DavidConrad I got that. maybe this is because Ubuntu runs it faster than windows on my machine so it reaches this line of code before the frame becoming active.

Comment: More likely the `setVisible(true)` that you presumably have in your `run()` method blocks on Windows until the frame is active, and returns immediately on Ubuntu, but whatever the reason, busy-waiting on it to become inactive is the wrong approach.

Comment: Don’t use a `while` loop for this.  Use a [WindowListener](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#addWindowListener(java.awt.event.WindowListener)).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is calling `isactive`  outside event thread. Use event listeners in your myFrame class to handle inactive state.